# Accessing Internet without WIFI or Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11

Theoretically, is it possible to access the internet through a browser without connecting to an ethernet cable or using WIFI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.There are several other ways to tether internet to your PC.

1. Bluetooth Tethering
2. Tether using USB cable from UE
3. A USB dongle with 2G/3G/LTE connectivity
4. Intel is also pushing chipsets with Simcard connectity. So it will be as simple as to put a sim card in your laptop and browse.

I'm sure there are some other alternatives too.The above mentioned are some of the options I can think of now.

Comment: Hypothetically, what would be safer for web browsing: using IEEE WIFI or 3G? If I am a hacker, what do I have a better chance of hacking without social engineering

Comment: If you have any additional questions, please do not post them as comments. However, "which is safer" is a very hard question to answer objectively and not really on topic here. It may be on topic on https://security.stackexchange.com, but I think you should check their help center first.

Answer (score 2):

In some parts of the world still dial up internet using a telephone wire and a modem is still a common way to access the internet.